# How can I improve locality of reads and writes in the following code?

Tags: c, performance, image-processing, cpu-cache

I'm working on the following image convolution code:

```c
typedef struct fmatrix{
    int rows;
    int cols;
    float** array;
} fmatrix;

typedef struct image{
    unsigned char* data;
    int w;
    int h;
    int c;
} image;

typedef struct kernel{
    fmatrix* psf;
    int divisor;
} kernel;

void convolve_sq(image* src, image* dst, kernel* psf, int pixel){
    int size = psf->psf->rows * psf->psf->cols;
    float tmp[size];
    int n, m; //for psf
    int x, y, x0, y0, cur; //for image

    y0 = pixel / (src->w * src->c);
    x0 = (pixel / src->c) % src->w;

    for (n = 0; n < psf->psf->rows; ++n){
        for (m = 0; m < psf->psf->cols; ++m){
            y = n - (psf->psf->rows / 2);
            x = m - (psf->psf->cols / 2);
            if ((y + y0) < 0 || (y + y0) >= src->h || (x + x0) < 0 || (x + x0) >= src->w){
                tmp[n*psf->psf->rows+m] = 255 * psf->psf->array[n][m];
            }
            else{
                cur = (pixel + y * src->w * src->c + x * src->c);
                tmp[n*psf->psf->rows+m] = src->data[cur] * psf->psf->array[n][m]; //misses on read
            }
        }
    }
    m = 0;
    for (n = 0; n < size; ++n){
        m += (int) tmp[n];
    }
    m /= psf->divisor;
    if (m < 0) m = 0;
    if (m > 255) m = 255;
    dst->data[pixel] = m; //misses on write
}

void convolve_image(image* src, image* dst, kernel* psf){
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < src->h; ++i){
        for (j = 0; j < src->w; ++j){
            for (k = 0; k < src->c; ++k){
                convolve_sq(src, dst, psf, (i * src->w * src->c + j * src->c + k) );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Running cachegrind, I've determined two places where there are a substantial number of cache misses, which I've annotated in the code above.  For the line marked "misses on read", there were 97,205 D1mr and 97,201 DLmr.  For the line marked "misses on write", there were 97,201 D1mw and DLmw.  These lines read and write directly to/from the image respectively.

How can I make this code more efficient, in terms of avoiding cache misses?

Comment: The high level answer is you need a working set that fits into cache. This paper goes into detail about cache access and offers some examples about how to code towards that: http://david.jobet.free.fr/wiclear-blog/images/cpumemory.pdf